# Save Table from MySQL as dictionary in Python with MySQL Connector

Tags: mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

Im trying to get Values from a MySQL Table and save them as a dictionary in Python, using MySQL connector since I couldnt manage to install anythingelse...

My problem is that it prints all key-value pairs, but only the last one/last row gets saved in the dictionary f[]. How do I get it to save every key-Value pair in the dictionary? 
Thanks in advance!

```js
import mysql.connector
import mysql

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="F", password="", host="localhost", db="f")

mycursor=conn.cursor(dictionary=True)

query = ("SELECT * FROM 'test')

mycursor.execute(query)

f={}

for row in mycursor:
  f = {row["JT"]: row ["f"]}
  print f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```js
for row in mycursor:
  f[row['JT']]=row["f"]
```